# Laravel Email validation message

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel and trying to fix a email validation message. The scenario is:

1. If I send empty value, the validator returns a response "The User Email field is required".
2. If I send an invalid value like 'my_email_id' [ without @ sign ], it still returns "The User Email field is required".
3. If I send empty value like 'my_email_id@domain', it still returns "The User Email must be a valid email address.".

Now, my question is how can I return the response "The User Email must be a valid email address." for Case 2 as well? Is there any way or is it just how Laravel does it by default?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make it with your custom validation message like this :

```
$rules = array(
        'email'=>'required|email|unique:users'
);

$messsages = array(
        'email.required'=>'The User Email must be a valid email address'
);

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messsages);
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a built-in [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation) for email addresses, and it just so happens that the examples directly solve your specific needs too.

You will need to look into using the **email validator** and **adding custom error messages**, both are documented in detail in the linked documentation.

However, I've gone ahead and combined the two solutions directly from the linked resource to solve your needs:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
   'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
], [
   'email.required' => 'The User Email must be a valid email address.'
)];
```